# How do I create a view where column names are defined from query return values

Tags: sql, database-design, pivot

First, my table layout:

**tblEquippedItems:** <-(table name)
slotid (FK), itemid (FK), charid (FK) <-(attributes)

So I have this table that describes the items a character has equipped. Slot id refers to the item slot where the item, denoted by itemid resides. Charid describes the character that has these items equipped.

What I'd like to do is present the data in some format like so:

Character Name | Shoulder Item | Head Item | Leg Item | ... |  <- Column Names

---

Zalbar | Shoulders of Penance | Helm of Penance | Leggings of Penance | ...  | <- Data values

^- This was my feeble attempt to represent a query result set.

I'd like to represent this as a view so I don't have to have an unnecessary and unstable table in the database. The column names will have to come from querying the lookup table that stores  the item slot names. Is there a way to programmatically define such a view? Dynamic SQL maybe? I'd love to avoid that...

Comment: What database (incl. version) is this for?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    [character].name                    AS [character_name],
    ISNULL([shoulder].name,'Nothing')   AS [shoulder_item_name],
    ISNULL([head].name,'Nothing')       AS [head_item_name],
    etc...
FROM
   [character]
LEFT JOIN
   [tblEquippedItems] AS [shoulder_item]
      ON [shoulder_item].charid = [character].id
      AND [shoulder_item].slotid = 1
LEFT JOIN
   [item]             AS [shoulder]
      ON [shoulder].id = [shoulder_item].itemid
LEFT JOIN
   [tblEquippedItems] AS [head_item]
      ON [head_item].charid = [character].id
      AND [head_item].slotid = 2
LEFT JOIN
   [item]             AS [head]
      ON [head].id = [head_item].itemid

etc...
```

Comment: +1 but don't forget to actually alias the columns, aka `as Shoulder Item`

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for in SQL Server 2005/2008 is a Pivot/Cross Tab.  You cannot define a View off of this as Views have to be predefined columns.  You can do it within a Stored Procedure though.

EDIT: For SQL Server 2000, look at this [article about Cross Tabs](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/dynamic-cross-tabs-pivot-tables).  Although you'll predominantly see Cross Tabs/Pivots use the Count() or Sum() aggregates, you can just as easily use Max() and Min() on text values.

Comment: Is Pivot available in SQL server 2000? (Which is what I BELIEVE I'm running on. I will double check though. It's my school's server and I hadn't run into version compatibility issues before...except when I wanted table variables :( )

Comment: `Pivot` was introduced in SQL 2005.  Prior to that you had to do quite a bit of manual work to create the Pivot.  Take a look at my edit for a link on how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to get some flack about the database design... a object-attribute-value table like this is considered "evil" for a variety of reasons.

That said, I use them to now and then too when database schemas need to be stable but the final list of attributes is in flux (and when I can live with the performance consequences).

You're at least on the right track by using VIEWs, which will allow you to make the schema more solid as the dust settles.

The bad news: although you can use PIVOT to make your life easier on the SQL side, but the query itself will need to be programmed with the actual column names you want.

There are three ways to do this:

1. Manually modify the VIEWs when you add/remove attributes (headache)
2. Dynamic queries (messy, slower, can't use a VIEW, need a PROCEDURE instead)
3. Create a stored procedure that uses dynamic SQL to drop/create all views after you modify the attributes (most complex)

Comment: Luckily this table is only used for reporting, so I don't really care about proper design and data integrity as that is all guaranteed in my other tables. This is simply to show a report of data already deemed to be consistent. :)

Answer (score 0):

Lots of self joins are in order i think

```
    SELECT t1.charid,t1.itemid as shoulders,t2.itemid as helm,t3.itemid as legs
FROM (SELECT charid,itemid from tblEquippedItems where slotid = 1) t1 //slotid = shuolders
INNER JOIN (SELECT itemid from tblEquippedItems where slotid = 2) t2 //slotid = Helm
ON t1.charid = t2.charid
INNER JOIN (SELECT itemid from tblEquippedItems where slotid = 3) t3 //slotid = Legs
ON t3.charid = t2.charid
```

Other than this, you could try a pivot

Comment: I like this idea. I forgot my basics for a second... (well, everything I do is relatively basic as I'm just a student.) As I've said in other comments, this table need not be optimized for anything at all really (There will only be one user.) and the data behind it is already solid and consistent.

Answer (score 0):

When I need to do cross-tabs or pivots, I generally do them outside the database.

I use MS Excel, with a query in it that extracts the data I need, in tabular form.  I then pivot in MS Excel to obtain a crosstabulated view with "dynamic column headers".

Excel is far from the only choice.  At the top end, you could use something like Cognos data cubes.